# F test for β1=β2 in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

If my model looks like this, Y=β0+β1X1+β2X2+β3X3+β4X4, and I want to perform an F test (5%) in R for β1=β2, how do I do it?
The only tutorials I can find online deal with β1=β2=0, but that's not what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've flagged your question to be moved to [Cross Validaded](http://stats.stackexchange.com) as it is a statistics question.

Comment: Fit a model `Y=β0+β12(X1+X2)+β3X3+β4X4` and compare the models with a likelihood ratio test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example in R testing whether the coefficient for `vs` is the same as the coefficient for `am`:

```
data(mtcars)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + disp + vs + am, data=mtcars)
library(car)
linearHypothesis(mod, "vs=am")
# Linear hypothesis test
# 
# Hypothesis:
#   vs - am = 0
# 
# Model 1: restricted model
# Model 2: mpg ~ hp + disp + vs + am
# 
# Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
# 1     28 227.07                           
# 2     27 213.52  1    13.547 1.7131 0.2016
```

Answer (score 1):

The `glht` function from `multcomp` package can do this (among others).  For example, if your model is

```
mod1 <-lm( y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)
```

then you can use:

```
summary(multcomp::glht(mod1, "x1-x2=0"))
```

Comment: Not that it is a dealbreaker, but to be clear: This is not performing an F-test, though, is it?

Comment: Good point. In this case though I think its identical.

Answer (score 1):

Run the model with and without the constraint and then use anova to compare them.  No packages are used.

```
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat, mtcars)
mod2 <- lm(mpg ~ I(cyl + disp) + hp + drat, mtcars) # constraint imposed
anova(mod2, mod1)
```

giving:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: mpg ~ I(cyl + disp) + hp + drat
Model 2: mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     28 252.95                           
2     27 244.90  1    8.0513 0.8876 0.3545
```

The underlying calculation is the following. It gives the same result as above.

```
L <- matrix(c(0, 1, -1, 0, 0), 1)  # hypothesis is L %*% beta == 0
q <- nrow(L) # 1
co <- coef(mod1)
resdf <- df.residual(mod1) # = nobs(mod1) - length(co) = 32 - 5 = 27
SSH <- t(L %*% co) %*% solve(L %*% vcov(mod1) %*% t(L)) %*% L %*% co
SSH/q # F value
##           [,1]
## [1,] 0.8876363
pf(SSH/q, q, resdf, lower.tail = FALSE) # p value
##           [,1]
## [1,] 0.3544728
```